# Url Rewriting not working on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

what I done with UrlRewriting.net is just working well while Im locally testing it,
it is not working on the internet why? is there any configuration?
I just did what ever ScottGu said:
[link text](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)

thanks inadvance

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="rewriter"  
             requirePermission="false" 
             type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
  </configSections>

  <system.web>

    <httpModules>
      <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
    </httpModules>

  </system.web>

  <rewriter>
    <rewrite url="~/products/books.html" to="~/products.aspx" />
  </rewriter>  

</configuration>
```

Comment: Provide more info, we can't guess what the problem is...

Comment: What's the behavior you're seeing? Are you running on IIS both times or are you using the development server locally?

Comment: And the error/exception you are getting? What OS is the internet version running on?

Comment: no error (just  error 404 page not found) it just not working  I test it on IIS7 in my computer it is working but it is not the case on the internet

Comment: @Kiarash: Make sure the AppPool runs under Integrated mode.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the important parts you'll need:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<configSections>
    <section name="rewriter" requirePermission="false"
        type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />

        </configSections>

        <system.web>
            <httpModules>
                <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
            </httpModules>
        </system.web>

        <system.webServer>
            <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
                <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule" />
            </modules>

                <!-- THE FOLLOWING LINE MUST BE PRESENT FOR AJAX & VALIDATION TO WORK WITH URLREWRITER.NET -->
                <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

            </handlers>
        </system.webServer>

        <!-- URL REWRITER -->
        <rewriter>
            <rewrite url="^~/About$" to="~/About.aspx" />
        </rewriter>
    </configuration>
```

My suggestion would be though, if you are able to use .Net 4, use URL Routing -it's way better.